# How to get attributes of join table with sequelize findAll()

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to join attributes of join table along with the main table.
But what's actually happening is that I am getting only main table attributes as a response.
I **need join table attributes in the response** as well.

Comment: Kindly share your code.

Comment: Kindly post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
 your_table
  .findAll({
    raw: true,
    include: [
      {
        model: <your_join_table>
      }
    ],
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.table(result);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```