# Sequelize-Typescript, include specific columns of join table in attributes of parent table

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, many-to-many, sequelize-typescript

I have a Many-to-Many association defined between two models "Role" and "Ressource", through a custom join table "RoleRessource", the join table contains an additional column "write". For the DB i am using Postgres.

```
class Role extends Model {
    @Unique
    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    name: string;

    @BelongsToMany(() => Ressource, () => RoleRessource)
    ressources: Ressource[];
}


class Ressource extends Model {
    @Unique
    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    name: string;

    @BelongsToMany(() => Role, () => RoleRessource)
    roles: Role[];
}


class RoleRessource extends Model {
    @ForeignKey(() => Role)
    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    roleId: number;

    @ForeignKey(() => Ressource)
    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    ressourceId: number;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Default(false)
    @Column
    write: boolean;
}
```

I can query the relation like so:

```
const roles = await Role.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Ressource,
            as: "ressources",
            through: { attributes: ['write'] },
            attributes: ["id", "name"],
        },
    ],
});
```

Which gives me this result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "TestRole",
        "ressources": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "TestRessource",
                "RoleRessource": {
                    "write": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The thing is i would like to include the column "write" at the ressource level like so:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "TestRessource",
  "write": false
}
```

I tried using `[col('RoleRessource.write'), 'write']` in the attributes field of ressource but i just get the error: "column ressources.RoleRessource.write does not exist".

I know i can also iterate over the ressources after the query and move the write one layer up, but i think there has to some proper way to solve this using sequelize.

Trying to include the join table like described here: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951135/how-to-get-attributes-of-join-table-with-sequelize-findall) result in this error: "RoleRessource is not associated to Role!"

Thanks in advance!